# I can't find what the error in this assembly language program is

Tags: assembly

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db 'Iqra University'
.code
dos_exit macro
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
end m
new_line macro
        mov dl,10
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
end m
main proc
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        new_line
        mov ah,09h
        mov dx ,offset msg
        int 21h
        dos_exit
        main endp
end main
```

Error

> End of file encountered on input file
>   lab04.asm(26) : warning A4085: End Of File , nO Directive

Comment: Please format the code appropriately. You can see how it looks while posting, please take note of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Try adding `end` on a line by itself at the end.